# Powershell to get unallocated/unassigned partitions in server 2012

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get unallocated partitions in a server 2012 machine. Whatever i found on the internet shows only named partitions but there are unnamed/unallocated partitions which i need to get. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by unallocated? Do you want disks that are formatted but not mounted? Or do you want to find unformatted free space within an existing partition table?

Comment: I am looking for all partitions details irrespective of they are mounted/unmounted and formatted/unformatted. Example LIKE this: 
DiskNumber PartitionNumber PartitionType DriverLetter DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus TotalSize SizeRemaining
---------- --------------- ------------- ------------ --------- ------------ ----------------- --------- -------------
         9               1 Reserved      NA                     NA           NA                128 MB                 
         9              NA NA            NA           NA        Unknown      Unknown           6842 GB   NA

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter -ne $null} | ForEach { 
  $Size = Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DriveLetter $_.DriveLetter 
  If ($Size.SizeMax -gt $_.Size) { $_ } 
}
```

Works fine on Windows 8/2012 server.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. It doesnot give partition details. I have pasted sample in the comment section above.